# Zoom H5 ASIO driver fails to open in Ableton Live

Tags: audio, zoom, asio

Ableton Live is unable to use the "H/F Series Stereo ASIO Driver" for Windows from here: https://zoomcorp.com/en/us/handheld-recorders/handheld-recorders/h5/h5-support/

It gives a "Failed to open" error.  Using the H5 as an audio interface causes cracks and pops with other drivers.

How do you get the H5 to work properly as an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Close Ableton Live, and then go to your Sound Settings.  Under "Output", choose "Speakers (H5)" and click "Device Properties", then go to "Additional device properties".  Choose advanced and check "Allow application to take exclusive control of this device."  Also make sure the bit rate is the same as the one being used on the H5.  Reopen Ableton Live and it should let you select it as an ASIO device now.